# Show File, Edit etc menu in title bar in XFCE

Tags: 16.04, xfce, window

I'd like to have a titlebar that has no title in it... instead it should display the menu (File, Edit, View, etc) and the standard buttons like minimize, maximize, etc. I'm using XFCE, not Unity.

So far I've found solutions on how to put the Menu in the top panel which is not what I want, unfortunately.

Something similar is done in Unity when window is not maximized. When it is maximized, though, you still get the menu at the top panel.

Basically, an average title bar should look like this:

```
File Edit Preferences About    <some empty space>    _ [] X
```

- It is acceptable that the title itself might not be visible at all
- It is also acceptable that, on the contrary, the menu might not be visible until I hover my mouse over it.
- Under no circumstances should this menu be in the top panel. Both minimized and maximized windows should still have their own combo-bar with title/menu on it.

How can I achieve that?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Xfce installed along with Unity and using the latter is not an option for me due to various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that what you want is possible, at least in Xubuntu 16.04.

Under `Settings` > `Window Manager`, what can be done is clear:

[image: Window Manager]

Comment: actually I have just such a situation where the windows have the menus but not the title bar, and therefore are also missing the minimize maximize close buttons; I got to this by installing the ubuntu server 18.04 followed by openbox and sudo apt-get install xfce4 lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter --no-install-recommends - after this, windows look normal with titlebars; then I took the deb packages and installed them on another laptop with sudo dpkg -i *deb, also looked fine; on the third laptop they are missing the titlebars - and in this case, the window manager dialog in settings does not start